# I have faced a problem to set Global color as default Elementor widget development

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

I have written this code( Please take a look at below), But it show this error """"

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Global_Typography' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\Test Plugin\widgets\test-widget.php:126 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php(1951): ETPWidget->_register_controls() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php(488): Elementor\Controls_Stack->init_controls() #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\widget-base.php(148): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_stack() #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php(294): Elementor\Widget_Base->get_stack() #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php(2040): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_controls() #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php(1012): Elementor\Controls_Stack->sanitize_settings(Array) #6 E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includ in E:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-content\plugins\Test Plugin\widgets\test-widget.php on line 126

""

$this->add_control(
'title_color',
[
'label' => __( 'Title Color', 'etpaddons' ),
'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
'scheme' => [
'type' => \Elementor\Scheme_Color::get_type(),
'value' => \Elementor\Scheme_Color::COLOR_1,
],
'global' => [
'default' => \Elementor\Global_Color::COLOR_PRIMARY,
],
'selectors' => [
'{{WRAPPER}} .etpaddons-heading' => 'color: {{VALUE}}',
],
]
);

Answer (score 1):

You have to import those namespaces first

```
use Elementor\Core\Kits\Documents\Tabs\Global_Colors;
use Elementor\Core\Kits\Documents\Tabs\Global_Typography;
```